I can't annotate text in R, connlu is created instead
So, I am trying to annotate the text of public telegram channel, I did that previously correct, but for some reason it just stopped working, and when I was trying annotate, I just got connlu df instead. I've tried things like downloading and do everything from the start, no results. Creating a sample df and annotating it works, at this point I just don't know, it's my case study for career. And now it says that my post is mostly code and I don't know how more to describe my code
studfreedom <- read_json("D://result.json")

messages <- studfreedom[["messages"]]

df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 7, nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- c("id", "type", "date", "date_unixtime", "from", "from_id", "text_data")
# parsing
for (i in 1:length(messages)) {
  if (is.list(messages[[i]]) && "text_entities" %in% names(messages[[i]]) && length(messages[[i]][["text_entities"]]) > 0) {
    if (length(messages[[i]][["text_entities"]]) == 1) {
      text_data <- messages[[i]][["text_entities"]][[1]][["text"]]
    } else {
      text_to_parse <- sapply(messages[[i]][["text_entities"]], function(x) ifelse(is.null(x[["text"]]), "", x[["text"]]))
      text_data <- paste(text_to_parse, collapse = " ")
    }
    new_row <- data.frame(
      id = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["id"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["id"]]),
      type = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["type"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["type"]]),
      date = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["date"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["date"]]),
      date_unixtime = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["date_unixtime"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["date_unixtime"]]),
      from = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["from"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["from"]]),
      from_id = ifelse(is.null(messages[[i]][["from_id"]]), NA, messages[[i]][["from_id"]]),
      text_data = ifelse(is.null(text_data), "", text_data),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE  # This option prevents strings from being converted to factors
    )
    df <- rbind(df, new_row)
  }
}

# Define the text cleaning function
clean_text_function <- function(text) {
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "[\U0001F600-\U0001F64F\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\U0001F700-\U0001F77F\U0001F780-\U0001F7FF\U0001F800-\U0001F8FF\U0001F900-\U0001F9FF\U0001FA00-\U0001FA6F\U0001FA70-\U0001FAFF\U00002702-\U000027B0\U000024C2-\U0001F251]+", "")
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+", "")
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "\\d{1,2}-\\d{1,2} [а-яА-Я]+ \\d{4} року", "")
  text <- tolower(text)
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "[[:punct:]]", " ")
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "\\d+", "")
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "\\s+", " ")
  text <- str_trim(text)
  text <- str_replace_all(text, "<[^>]*>", "")
  return(text)
}

# Apply the function to clean the text
df$text_data <- sapply(df$text_data, clean_text_function)

# Download and load the Ukrainian language model
ukr_model <- udpipe_download_model(language = "ukrainian")
udmodel_ukr <- udpipe_load_model(file = ukr_model$file_model)

# Annotate the cleaned text with the model
annotated_text <- udpipe_annotate(udmodel_ukr, x = df$text_data)

# Convert the list of annotations to a data frame
annotated_text <- do.call(rbind, annotated_text)
annotated_text <- as.data.frame(annotated_text)

I tried that with not filtered text, did not help too

Welcome to SO @Viktor Batih. Because the rest of us can't read what's in your D drive path: read_json("D://result.json") I suggest using a small reproducible example (reprex) so others can help you out.
